# If a page has fewer external links, will the linked pages get more SEO benefit?

Tags: seo, backlinks

Does it matter whether a page externally links to 1 or 10 pages, from the POV of the pages linked? Would they somehow receive lesser SEO benefits as in less visibility or link juice (even though I think that term is now obsolete)

Comment: Link juice is not obsolete.   Google PageRank is still a huge part of Googles ranking algorithm.   It is a bit less important than it used to be because Google has added more ranking factors and created algorithms that detect link juice manipulation.  It is also less visible than it used to be because Google no longer publicly publishes PageRank metrics for any site.